# Interior of a set

Tags: real-analysis

A  dual notion to the closure of a set is the interior of a set. The Interior of E is denoted $E^o$ and is defined as: $E^{o}=$ { $ x \in E :$ there exists $ V_{\epsilon } \left ( x \right )\subseteq E$}.

Results about closures and interiors posses a useful symmetry.

(a) Show that E is closed if and only if $\overline{E}=E$. Show that E is open if and only if $E^{o}=E$.

(b) Show that $\overline{E}^{c}=\left ( E^{c} \right )^{o}$, and similarly that $\left ( E^{o} \right )^{c}=\overline{E^{c}}$.

My Attempt:

[image]

Is this correct? Does it satisfy the requirements of the question?

Comment: Okay... but what is your question?

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask if this was a sufficient answer.